# Integer Spacing (python)

Tags: python, range, difference

I'm trying to do is determine if the inputs(integers) have even difference between them

Example if my inputs are:

```
1

3

5
```

it will then print `True`

This is my current code:

```
x = int(raw_input (""))
y = int(raw_input (""))
z = int(raw_input (""))
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
z = int(z)
list_a = [x,y,z]

if list_a[1] == list_a[0]+2 and \
    list_a[2] == list_a[1]+2:
    print True
else:
     print 'False'
```

is there an easier way that i can cover **all even range**
ex: *if the inputs are 5, 10 and 15 or 10, 20, 30?*

Comment: You should tag your question with at least, a language, use the proper code "tag" so code is not mixed with text.

Comment: Hint: Loop through the list, and use modulo operation to check if difference is even or odd.

Comment: @shree.pat18: I was thinking the same as you did, but I've just realized he probably meant "even" as in "the same", not even/odd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can compare the difference between the items in the list.

For a list with 3 items:

```
if list_a[2] - list_a[1] == list_a[1] - list_a[0]:
  print True 
else:
  print False
```

If the list has more items:

```
function isEvenlyDistributed(list){
  for(idx = 2; idx < list.size; idx++):
    if(list[idx] - list[idx-1] != list[idx-1] - list[idx-2])
      return false;
  return true; /* never returned false, so true at the end */
}
```

edit: python tag was added. This is pseude-code, so you should convert it to python :)

Comment: It was asked for an even difference between the items, not for exactly the same difference. This answer does not really answer the question.

Comment: @Nras sorry if my question is confusing its even(ly) not even(numbers)

Comment: @Nras you can remove the -1 now :p

Comment: @Fortega once i realized i was the one (as well as the comment from shree.pat18 showed how he understood it) i tried to remove -1, but the vote is locked after a certain time, unless the answer is edited.